Soldering flux and cleaner for analog SMT boards
I decided to build some precision analog circuits and will need to solder a few parts (on a surface mount board). So far I have soldered almost exclusively digital or non-precision analog and almost exclusively through-hole (and I have to admit I have not used flux) so I am trying to study what is best.
I have seen in many places (e.g. here) that it would be better not to use no-clean flux. I am having a hard time finding it, since most hobby places such as Adafruit or Sparkfun (and to a degree even professional ones such as DigiKey or Mouser) stock big variety of no-clean and very few, if any "clean" ones. On top of that, searching for no-noclean appears to confound most search engines. On Amazon is even harder to search.
Also, it's not clear what/how is best to use to clean each kind of flux.
Questions:

Am I really better off going with this trouble to find a product that I seem to be unable to find, or am I wasting my time/resources, and I can assume that everything stocked by a reputable store will be good enough?
Any recommendation of a typology of flux product (or even better a specific product you use, which I know may be not appropriate to recommend) which is easy to use for a relative beginner and is not excessively toxic to use? I am leaning towards RMA (since all the boards and components will be brand-new, hence I probably don't need something very corrosive).
Identical question to the above for a solvent to use for cleaning, which works well for the flux above? Some people say that RMA can be cleaned with home isopropyl alcohol (typically sold to disinfect "minor cuts"), some say you have to use 99% or higher purity. Do I really?

For the toxicity, this is one-off project, which I will solder outdoors with air circulated at most with a fan. Being a one-off thing, I am not worried too much about the long-term toxicity of the products, and more about their immediate irritant characteristics
Many products seem to have some reviews from somebody saying how bad they are either in performance or irritant, so I am having a hard time deciding.

How will you do the soldering, by hand or in a reflow oven?

I was thinking by hand with soldering iron, but I do have an old toaster over which I could dedicate to this if I find that it's easier/better for a beginner (but I suspect it'll not be the case).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is likely to get closed as a shopping question, but you may find these of use: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/good-soldering-flux/ https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/flux-categories/ or join and ask your own questions; discussion forums are often better suited to these sorts of topics, than Stack is.

The usual-kind of "no-clean" or "water-soluble" fluxes are very bad for analog circuits with high-impedance nodes. I have had very bad experiences even with regular digital (SMOS) circuits. These fluxes are hydrophilic and will make parasitic leakages down to few kOhm when in normal lab environment, so depending on relative air humidity you might have very surprising and highly unstable results. You will have to use some hot-water ultrasonic cleaners to carefully remove all residuals from boards.
For small soldering jobs I use a rosin-based "mildly activated" flux like Kester 186 Flux-Pen,

and a solder wire with rosin core as well.
